# How To do json type Response?

Tags: ios, objective-c, image, video, uicollectionview

I have one collection view in that I have to show images and video coming from backend I'm very new to do this I'm getting this response from backend.

```
SliderList =     (
            {
        SliderID = 1;
        SliderType = 1;
        SliderURL = "http://mca.bananaappscenter.com/Images/SliderImages/MaskGroup2.png";
        Status = 1;
    },
            {
        SliderID = 2;
        SliderType = 1;
        SliderURL = "http://mca.bananaappscenter.com/Images/SliderImages/MaskGroup3.png";
        Status = 1;
    },
            {
        SliderID = 3;
        SliderType = 2;
        SliderURL = "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=l1yN0KUHgoc";
        Status = 1;
    }
);
}
```

and I did like this

```
 NSMutableDictionary *sampleDict = [ImagesArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    NSString *imageStr = [[NSString alloc]init];
    imageStr = [sampleDict valueForKey:@"SliderURL"];

    if([imageStr isEqualToString:@"1"] || imageStr == nil)
    {
        cell.addImageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@""];
    }
    else
    {
        [cell.addImageView sd_setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:imageStr]
                                placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"default"]];`
    }
```

for above only images coming. if any Answer it would be appreciated. Thanks in Advance.

Comment: plz add additional code

Comment: if(requestType == RequestTypeHomeSlider)
             
                {
                    NSLog(@"%@",responseObject);
                    NSString *respCode =[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [responseDict valueForKey:@"StatusCode"]];
                    if([respCode isEqualToString:@"200"])
                    {
                        ImagesArray= [NSMutableArray new];
                        ImagesArray = [responseObject valueForKey:@"SliderList"];

                        [_imageCollectionView reloadData];
                    }

Comment: plz add additional code

Comment: Hi @karthik which code you want? please tell me

Comment: related to your collectionview code or add entire class code in your question

Comment: @ hi Karthik can you please add I will send the code?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/184010/discussion-between-anbu-karthik-and-santoshi).

Comment: check the condition for   "if SliderType = 2" . display some  thumbnail or default image for video item

Comment: @Helo Pradeep can you please tell me how to differentiate

Comment: As i can see from ur json response  SliderType is the key thru which u can able to detect whether its image or video.. First parse the SliderURL nd SliderType.. nd then check if SliderURL != nil{ if  SliderType == 2{ //video data}else if sliderType==1{//image data}else{//nothng} .  }

Comment: can you please give me an example?

Comment: check my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got Answer for my question thank you every one who responded to me

```
 if ([ImagesArray[indexPath.row][@"SliderType"] intValue]==1) {

                NSString *imageStr=ImagesArray[indexPath.row][@"SliderURL"];

                [cell.addImageView sd_setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:imageStr]
                                         placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"default"]];

                }else if ([ImagesArray[indexPath.row][@"SliderType"] intValue]==2) {

                    NSString *imageStr=ImagesArray[indexPath.row][@"SliderURL"];
                    [cell.addImageView sd_setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:imageStr]
                                         placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"VideoButton"]];

                }
```

Answer (score 0):

As I understand from question and your extended discussion on chat you are facing trouble with showing video in cell along with Images. In order to show video along with image you will need to use a different approach.

- First thing you need to do is to find if this is video URL or image. Best way to do that will be to segregate that by adding a parameter in your web-service which indicate if this is a image or video.
- Once that is out of system you will need a special view that can load video perfectly i have used [this library](https://github.com/youtube/youtube-ios-player-helper) and it works fine.
- Now in your cell add both `imageView` and video player view, and add a condition where you check if it's video then display `YTPlayerView` or imageView based on returned information.

Then with help pf these function you can load video on your player View:

```
+ (NSString *)extractYoutubeIdFromLink:(NSString *)link {
    if (link == nil) nil;

    NSString *regexString = @"((?<=(v|V)/)|(?<=be/)|(?<=(\\?|\\&)v=)|(?<=embed/))([\\w-]++)";
    NSRegularExpression *regExp = [NSRegularExpression regularExpressionWithPattern:regexString
                                                                            options:NSRegularExpressionCaseInsensitive
                                                                              error:nil];

    NSArray *array = [regExp matchesInString:link options:0 range:NSMakeRange(0,link.length)];
    if (array.count > 0) {
        NSTextCheckingResult *result = array.firstObject;
        return [link substringWithRange:result.range];
    }
    return nil;
}


//Write this line on your function where you want to load video
[_videoView loadWithVideoId:[SCUtility extractYoutubeIdFromLink:_videoURL]];
```

Answer (score 0):

I have added code in swift lang .. You can take reference and apply same logic there. It will work

```
   let ImagesArray =     [
    [
        "SliderID" : 1,
        "SliderType" : 1,
        "SliderURL" : "http://mca.bananaappscenter.com/Images/SliderImages/MaskGroup2.png",
        "Status" : 1
    ],
    [
        "SliderID" : 2,
        "SliderType" : 1,
        "SliderURL" : "http://mca.bananaappscenter.com/Images/SliderImages/MaskGroup3.png",
        "Status" : 1
    ],
    [
        "SliderID" : 3,
        "SliderType" : 2,
        "SliderURL" : "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=l1yN0KUHgoc",
        "Status" : 1
    ]
    ]
```

In tableview cellforrow u can implement like this   :

```
    let sampleDict = ImagesArray[indexPath.row] as? NSDictionary
    let SliderURL = sampleDict.valueForkey("SliderURL") as? String
     let SliderType = sampleDict.objectForkey("SliderType") as? NSNumber

    if SliderURL != nil{
        //means url abvl
        if SliderType == 2{
            //video data
            cell.addImageView.image = "set video default thumbnail image "

        }else if SliderType == 1{
            //imagedata
           // cell.addImageView.image = "set ur image "
        }
    }
```

**In Objective C**

```
    NSMutableDictionary *sampleDict = [ImagesArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
NSString *imageStr = [[NSString alloc]init];
imageStr = [sampleDict valueForKey:@"SliderURL"];
```

// NSString * SliderType = [[NSString alloc]init];
   // SliderType = [sampleDict valueForKey:@"SliderType"];

```
 int SliderType = [[sampleDict valueForKey:@"SliderType"] integerValue];
  NSLog(@"%i", SliderType);

if(imageStr != nil)
{

   //if([SliderType isEqualToString:@"2"]
    if [SliderType isEqualToNumber:[NSNumber numberWithInt:2]] {

    cell.addImageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"default"];

  }else if [SliderType isEqualToNumber:[NSNumber numberWithInt:1]] {

  [cell.addImageView sd_setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:imageStr]
                            placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"default"]];`
  }else{
      //nothng
  }
}
else
{
    //SliderURL is nil
}
```

Comment: your SliderType data is of number type.. first fetch in number/Int type

Comment: int SliderType = [sampleDict[@"SliderType"] integerValue];